Why does \appendix reset the counter of the level below the main sectioning level?
In book.cls \appendix is defined as:
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}

While in article.cls it is:
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}

It is clear why \appendix has to reset the counter for the main sectioning level of the document class. But I don't seem to be able to understand why the next level below is also (explicitly) reset. That is, why does \appendix in book.cls also reset the section counter and in article.cls also reset the subsection counter?
The same pattern seems to be common, at least in: KOMA-Script classes, Memoir, appendix package.
texdoc classes does not seem to disclose the reason for this.
However, I wouldn't expect an immediate sectioning command below the main level immediately after \appendix, e.g. a \section immediately after \appendix in the book class, without a previous call to \chapter, etc. If that's the case, whatever the main level sectioning command is, \refstepcounter should reset the level below anyway. Why is it then done explicitly in \appendix then?
"Historical reasons"? Or is there some use case(s) that makes this really necessary?

some documents use continuous numbering in the main body of the document, but would presumably want separate numbering for the appendix. so you might have 1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 4.7, A.1, B.2, B.3, C.4 etc. see e.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr which offers counterwithout as well as counterwithin. (you don't need the package these days, but it's easier to point to.)

@cfr The separate numbering for the sublevels is already ensured by \refstepcounter as long as long as the main level is reset. And who would use \counterwithout on section commands? But, OK, let's admit it is this possibility of such change by the user, shouldn't it then reset all levels down to subparagraph?

It's not documented but it's been that way forever.
I assume it's because otherwise the section counter would only be reset if there was a numbered \chapter but often you only have one appendix so people often want
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix}

but then as \chapter* doesn't reset the counters the section countering would pick up from the previous chapter if it hadn't been reset.
This all predates LaTeX2e, the final LaTex2.09 release (available as an archive on ctan) has in bk12.doc
% BOOK STANDARD DOCUMENT STYLE -- Released 14 Jan 1992
...
% APPENDIX
%
% The \appendix command must do the following:
%    -- reset the chapter counter to zero
%    -- set \@chapapp to Appendix (for messages)
%    -- redefine the chapter counter to produce appendix numbers
%    -- reset the section counter to zero
%    -- redefine the \chapter command if appendix titles and headings
%       are to look different from chapter titles and headings.
 
\def\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}

which at least documents that this happens intentionally, if not documenting why.

But why would one use a numbered section after an unnumbered chapter? If you do \appendix \chapter*{Appendix} \section{Section} you get ".1 Section"...

@gusbrs I think it's quite common if you have two things that could be appendices but don't need flashy chapter level titles to have appendix then numbered sections. yes you'd need to reset \thesection  but that's within the range of things expected by someone who had only read the latexbook.  But it's all a bit speculative: The real answer is "Leslie thought it was a good idea 40 years ago",

bk12.sty in latex2.09 has \def\appendix{\par   \setcounter{chapter}{0}%   \setcounter{section}{0}%   \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}%   \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}

Yeah, but someone changing \thesection manually like that, would just as well know to reset the counter if that's what they need. But I think I get the gist: basically "historical". And "everybody does it" because the standard classes do, I guess. I really expected some more flashy reason for how widespread the practice is, though.   ;-) I'll accept since it is what it is, and I couldn't hope for someone more seasoned to tell me "it's been around for ages". Thank you!

@gusbrs I added  some documentation of this from 1992 to the answer

I've seen it, thanks again. Btw, intentionality is also clear in texdoc classes, it is just the reason which is missing (for a long time as well, it seems ;-);
